# Whose blood did Carol Danvers receive, Mar-vell's or Yon-Rogg's in the movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

I recently watched the Captain Marvel movie (2019) and understood that Yon-Rogg claims that Carol/Vers received his blood in a transfusion that saved her life.

Was Yon-Rogg lying to Carol/Vers when he said this or was her DNA fused with Mar-Vell's as part of the explosion that led to her becoming Captain Marvel?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The way I understood it, Carol was infused with the *energy* from Mar-Vell's engine, but her Kree blood is from Yon-Rogg.

- By the time the engine blows up, Mar-Vell is in no shape to be giving blood transfusions.
- The way the topic of the transfusion comes up means that we have no reason to doubt it, or at least no reason to doubt that that's how Carol remembers it.
- Carol undoubtedly has blue (Kree) blood, yet The Great Intelligence is unable to take away her powers - because said powers don't come from The Great Intelligence. In other words, her powers and her Kree traits have two different sources.

(All of this is based on the movie only - I've never so much as encountered a Captain Marvel comic book.)

Comment: This was my understanding/interpretation as well from the movie, I was wondering if her DNA/blood was fused w/ Mar-Vell's when the engine explode though.

Comment: @slm They didn't fuse. I found it pretty clear as to what happened

Comment: The blood transfusion on Hala was from Yon-Rogg, that's made clear. I was willing to believe that the explosion of the engine was similar enough to her original origin (which has, I believe, been changed in the comics) that the DNA-mixing from Mar-Vell MAY indeed have happened, and could have served as a catalyst in making her capable of absorbing the energy, as opposed to being reduced to a fine red mist.

Comment: @VBartilucci IIRC, from the positions they were standing in, the blast would have pushed Danvers's blood over Mar-Vell's body if anything of that sort happened

Comment: "*Carol undoubtedly has blue (Kree) blood.*" Does Carol have blue blood? She had red blood during the plane crash.

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro, there is a later scene where she has a nosebleed, and the blood is blue.

Answer (score 7):

Given it was used as a test by Yon-Rogg to determine whether or not it was the real Danvers he was speaking to and the Skrull's inability to answer was enough for Yon-Rogg to shoot the Skrull, he would have to be pretty certain that the real Danvers would know (or at least believe) she had received Yon-Rogg's blood.

Additionally, Mar-Vell's engine was not necessarily anything to do with Kree technology. It was mentioned by a Skrull, iirc Thalos(?) that her powers exhibited the same energy signature as the engine, which would suggest that all the explosion gave her was Tesseract power, something that is unlikely to give Danvers Kree blood since the Tesseract's power pertains to space.

Comment: The light-speed engine actually is Kree technology. Similar to how Hydra was harnessing the tesseracts power to charge their weaponry. The weaponry is still human technology, but it's powered by an infinity stone. The explosion gave Carol Danvers her powers, because it is explicitly shown to be the source of her powers in the movie.

Comment: The engine was *developed* by a Kree (Mar-vell) but it's made clear in the film this is novel: neither Vers not Yon-Rogg had previously heard of such a thing, and Talos implied the Kree (nor anyone else, apparently) had nothing like it.

Answer (score 0):

Carol's blood was blue right after the explosion. Either the explosion caused her blood to be blue or she fused wit Mar Vell. (After the explosion, there was no longer any sight of the body)

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This answer would be improved if you could edit in some screenshots or video demonstrating that Carol's blood was blue during the explosion. I personally don't remember any blood during that scene, just wisps of energy.

Comment: She did not have blue blood right after the explosion.